# How do I mangle namespace generation in SOAP::Lite?

Tags: perl, wsdl, cxf, xml-namespaces, soaplite

Scenario:

- The client is a Perl script using [SOAP::Lite](http://p3rl.org/SOAP%3a%3aLite).
- The server is a Java based application using Spring and CXF.

My client is producing based on the WSDL the following SOAP request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <createFolder xmlns="http://xyz.com/">
            <parentId xsi:type="xsd:string">1</parentId>
            <folderName xsi:type="xsd:string">Test</folderName>
        </createFolder>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This request will fail against CXF. After several investigations I found out that the following manually produced request will work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xyz="http://xyz.com/">
    <soap:Body>
        <xyz:createFolder>
            <parentId xsi:type="xsd:string">1</parentId>
            <folderName xsi:type="xsd:string">Test</folderName>
        </xyz:createFolder>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The difference is the namespace definition for the element `createFolder`.

My question is: **How can I configure SOAPLite to create the working SOAP request?**

Or vice versa: **How can CXF be configured to accept the SOAP::Lite request style?**

Comment: It also could be a configuration issue of CXF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look under [`ns`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?SOAP%3a%3aLite#ns%28%24uri,%24prefix=undef%29). If gives a similarly qualified name for root element of the fragment

Using the following:

```
SOAP::Lite->new->proxy( 'http://somewhere.com' )
    ->ns( 'http://xyz.com/', 'xyz' )->createFolder( 
      SOAP::Data->new( name => 'parentId',   value => 1, type => 'xsd:string' )
    , SOAP::Data->new( name => 'folderName', value => 'Test' ) 
    );
```

I got the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
    xmlns:xyz="http://xyz.com/" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
>
  <soap:Body>
    <xyz:createFolder>
      <parentId   xsi:type="xsd:string">1</parentId>
      <folderName xsi:type="xsd:string">Test</folderName>
    </xyz:createFolder>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And I think that's what you want.